# Delete words in Word Document that are not in Excel list

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I'm working on a school project where I have a lot of Word Documents and I want to remove all words in those documents that are not on a specific list that I have in Excel. I've never worked with both Excel and Word and I've used clunky find and delete options in both individually but I have a lot of documents and doing this in a brute force method seems like it'll take too long.

The documents I have are transcripts of conversations so I want to keep the words chronologically in the same place if possible, but I want to remove filler words that are not related to the words I am interested in. I have a list of words that I am interested in in an Excel document, but I'm not sure how to search through the whole document and have the words that are not in my Excel list deleted.

EDIT: I've found a lot of find and replace macros but I'm trying to figure out how to have every word that is not on my excel list deleted.

Thank you all in advance for your time.

Comment: A vba loop using the list in Excel and find/replace in Word? Many examples of vba and loops on here.

Comment: Load the Excel list into a dictionary, then check each word in the Doc to see if it's listed or not

Answer (score 1):

For example, supposing you have an Excel workbook named WordList.xlsx in your Documents folder:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim xlApp As Object, xlWkBk As Object, StrWkBkNm As String
Dim xlFList As String, i As Long
StrWkBkNm = "C:\Users\" & Environ("Username") & "\Documents\WordList.xlsx"
If Dir(StrWkBkNm) = "" Then
  MsgBox "Cannot find the designated workbook: " & StrWkBkNm, vbExclamation
  Exit Sub
End If
'Get the folder to process
strFolder = GetFolder
If strFolder = "" Then Exit Sub
On Error Resume Next
'Start Excel
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
If xlApp Is Nothing Then
  MsgBox "Can't start Excel.", vbExclamation
  Exit Sub
End If
On Error GoTo 0
With xlApp
  'Hide our Excel session
  .Visible = False
  ' The file is available, so open it.
  Set xlWkBk = .Workbooks.Open(StrWkBkNm, False, True)
  If xlWkBk Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Cannot open:" & vbCr & StrWkBkNm, vbExclamation
    .Quit: Set xlApp = Nothing: Exit Sub
  End If
  ' Process the workbook.
  With xlWkBk
    With .Worksheets(1)
      ' Find the last-used row in column A and capture the F data.
      For i = 1 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(-4162).Row ' -4162 = xlUp
        ' Skip over empty fields to preserve the underlying cell contents.
        If Trim(.Range("A" & i)) <> vbNullString Then xlFList = xlFList & "|" & Trim(.Range("A" & i))
      Next
    End With
    .Close False
  End With
  .Quit
End With
' Release Excel object memory
Set xlWkBk = Nothing: Set xlApp = Nothing
'Exit if there are no data
If xlFList = "" Then Exit Sub
strFile = Dir(strFolder & "\*.doc", vbNormal)
'Process each document in the folder
While strFile <> ""
  If strFolder & "\" & strFile <> strDocNm Then
    Set wdDoc = Documents.Open(FileName:=strFolder & "\" & strFile, AddToRecentFiles:=False, Visible:=False)
    'Process each word from the F/R List
    With wdDoc
      With .ActiveWindow.View
        bHid = .ShowHiddenText
        .ShowHiddenText = True
      End With
      'Format all content as hidden text
      .Range.Font.Hidden = True
      With .Range.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Font.Hidden = True
        .Replacement.Font.Hidden = False
        .Format = True
        .Forward = True
        .MatchWholeWord = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Replacement.Text = "^& "
        'Unhide each item from the Find List
        For i = 1 To UBound(Split(xlFList, "|"))
          .Text = Split(xlFList, "|")(i)
          .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        Next
        'Delete any remaining hidden text
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .Text = ""
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
      End With
      .ActiveWindow.View.ShowHiddenText = bHid
      'Close the document
      .Close SaveChanges:=True
    End With
  End If
  'Get the next document
  strFile = Dir()
Wend
Set wdDoc = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
 
Function GetFolder() As String
Dim oFolder As Object
GetFolder = ""
Set oFolder = CreateObject("Shell.Application").BrowseForFolder(0, "Choose a folder", 0)
If (Not oFolder Is Nothing) Then GetFolder = oFolder.Items.Item.Path
Set oFolder = Nothing
End Function
```